# Kähler differential over a field

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, homology-cohomology

I have been working with Kähler differentials, and I have $\Omega^1_{B/k}$, where B is a commutative $k$-algebra, and $k$ is a field. I was wondering that for $d(b)=0$, does this imply that $b\in k$? I know that there are examples, however, like in $\Omega^1_{\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}}$ we have that $d(\alpha)=0$ iff $\alpha$ is algebraic. But since I am over a field, I thought maybe this will force $b\in k$ in my case? Any hint or guidance would be most helpful!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$da=0$ does not imply that $a\in k.$ Here is my example.

Let $B=k^{\{0,1\}},$ i.e. functions on $\{0,1\}$ with values in $k.$ Product in algebra $B$ is given by pointwise multiplication, i.e. $p:B\otimes B\to B$ is given by formula
$$p(f\otimes g)(x)=f(x)g(x), x=0,1.$$

Consider elements $a,b\in B$ such that $$a(0)=0, a(1)=1,b(0)=1,b(1)=-1$$

We see that $ab=-a,a^2=a$ and $b+2a=1.$

From construction of Kahler differential we know that $\Omega_{B/k}=I/I^2$ where $I=\ker{p}.$ Consider
$$b(1\otimes a-a\otimes 1)(1\otimes a-a\otimes 1)=b(1\otimes a^2-2a\otimes a+a^2\otimes 1)=b(1\otimes a-2a\otimes a+a\otimes 1)=b\otimes a+ 2a\otimes a-a\otimes 1=(b+2a)\otimes a - a\otimes 1=1\otimes a-a\otimes 1.$$
From construction of Kahler differential we also know that $da=[1\otimes a-a\otimes 1].$ We proved that $(1\otimes a-a\otimes 1)\in I^2,$ so $da=0.$ On the other hand we easily see that $a\notin k.$

$k\hookrightarrow B$ is obviously indentified as constant functions.

---

My idea is based on the fact from calculus which says, that functions with property $df=0$ are **locally** constant. Here I split domain into just two points 0 and 1.

Comment: I like this - it is very constructive. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

If $B$ is a separable field extension of $k$ then in fact $\Omega^1_{B/k} = 0$: indeed, if $x \in B$ has minimal polynomial $f \in k[t]$, separable by assumption, then $f(x) = 0$ implies $f'(x)\,dx = 0$ and since $B$ is a field, $dx = 0$.

Comment: What if we assume $k$ is algebraically (or separably) closed and that $B$ is a (smooth?) domain? I think there is something reasonable behind this question, since from calculus we know that a function which has derivative zero is locally constant.

Comment: I meant to say that $B$ should be finite type over $k$ as well.

Comment: Never mind - weird things of course happen in characteristic $p$: such as $x^p \in k[x]$. So if you assume that $char=0$, I guess some positive statement follows from some application of the Lefschetz principle + calculus... not sure.

Comment: @AreaMan: If you assume all that you said or perhaps a bit less, it should follow from the theorem of generic smoothness (a non-constant map from $\mathop{\mathrm{Spec}}B$ to $\mathbb{A}^1$ will be generically smooth, hence have a nonzero differential by the first fundamental exact sequence), or something.  And $B$ being a domain should suffice because it, too, will be generically smooth.  (I didn't check the details, I may have missed something, though.)

Comment: I don't really get what you mean by the first theorem you cite. (I think understand the statement, and the functor that $A^1$ represents, and I also know the first fundamental exact sequence, but the conclusion that there is a nonzero differential loses me. What about the example of $x^p$, as map $\mathbb{A}^1 \to \mathbb{A}^1$ in char = p? It is something in char = 0? I am prepared to believe in characteristic zero, or as long as we avoid Frobenius.) Can you give me a reference or expand upon it a little? (Googling generic smoothness gives me the second result.)

Comment: @AreaMan: Yes, it is something in characteristic zero: if $Y\to X$ is a morphism of algebraic varieties over a field of characteristic $0$ with $Y$ smooth, then there is a dense open set $X$ over which the morphism is smooth (or, if you're willing to restrict to a dense open set of $Y$ as well, you can remove the hypothesis "$Y$ smooth"). See e.g., Hartshorne, *Algebraic Geometry*, cor. 10.7 (he assumes $k$ algebraically closed but it seems unnecessary).

Comment: @AreaMan: As to why smoothness implies a nonzero differential, an addendum to the first fundamental exact sequence $f^*\Omega_{X/S}\to\Omega_{Y/S}\to\Omega_{Y/X}\to 0$ is that if $Y$ is smooth over $X$ then the first map is injective (see, e.g., Matsumura, *Commutative Ring Theory*, thm 25.1). Apply this to $f\colon Y\to\mathbb{A}^1_k$: then $df\in\Omega_{Y/k}$ is in fact the image of $dt$ (with $t$ the coordinate on the line), and it is nonzero.

Comment: PS: I'm sure there must be a simpler way of saying all of this. :-)

Comment: Ah thank you! This has been most helpful. I just kept failing to get a good grasp on the differentials, but this has given me insight as to how to sink my teeth into them.