# If $K$ is a finite separable extension of $F$, show that there is a $K$-vector space isomorphism $Der_k(F)\otimes_F K \simeq Der_k(K)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, tensor-products

I'm studying about derivation algebra in *Morandi*'s book *Field and Galois Theory*.

There are one of problem as following:

If $K$ is a finite separable extension of $F$, show that there is a $K$-vector
space isomorphism

$Der_k(F)\otimes_F K \simeq Der_k(K)$

where $Der_k(F)$ is the $k$-derivation on $F$.

Comment: This answer from http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1713741/201873 might help.

Answer (score 0):

$$\newcommand{\Der}{\mathrm{Der}}$$
$$\newcommand{\tensor}{\otimes}$$

Although one could prove this via modules of Kähler-differentials quite easily, using standard propositions, I will try to give a direct proof:

First let for rings $k \to R$ and an $R$-module $M$ be $\Der_k(R,M)$ the $R$-Module of derivations from $R$ to $M$ which vanish at $k$. Further let, following your notation, $\Der_k(R) = \Der_k(R,R)$.

About the field $K$, we note $K=F(\alpha) = F[x]/f(x)$ with $f \in F[x]$ irreducible of degree, say, $n$.

Now we have first

$$\Der_k(F) \tensor_F K = \Der_k(F,K)$$

The maps here are as follows: Let $\delta = \sum_i \delta_i \tensor_F \gamma_i$ be an element of the left side. It gives a derivation, element of the right side by

$$\hat{\delta}(f) = \sum_i \delta_i(f) \gamma_i$$

where one easily checks $\hat{\delta}(f_1 f_2) = f_1 \hat{\delta}(f_2) + f_2 \hat{\delta}(f_1)$.

Starting from the right side, one notices 
$$\Der_k(F,K) = \Der_k(F,F^n) = \Der_k(F,F) \tensor_F F^n = \Der_k(F) \tensor_F K$$
as $F$-modules.

To put it more concrete: Calling

$$p_i(\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} a_j \alpha^j) = a_i$$

we associate to $\delta \in \Der_k(F,K)$ the $n$-tuple $(\delta_i = p_i \circ \delta \in \Der_k(F))_{i=0,\ldots,n-1}$. Then we set

$$\widetilde{\delta} = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \delta_i \tensor_F \alpha^i \in \Der_k(F) \tensor_F K$$

The associations $\delta \mapsto \hat{\delta}$ resp. $\delta \mapsto \widetilde{\delta}$ from left to right resp. from right to left are inverse to each other, as one checks by a simple calculation. They are both $F$-linear, and the first is $K$-linear. So the second, as the inverse of the first is $K$-linear too.

Now we have to prove

$$\Der_k(F,K) = \Der_k(K,K)$$

For this we introduce for $k \to R \to S$ and $x \in S$ and $g \in R[x]$ and $\delta \in \Der_k(R,S)$ the map

$$g(x) = \sum_j a_j x^j \mapsto g^\delta(x) = \sum_j \delta(a_j) x^j$$

Starting from $\delta \in \Der_k(F,K)$ we define $\hat{\delta} \in \Der_k(K,K)$ by ($g(x) \in F[x]$):

$$\hat{\delta}(g(\alpha)) = g^\delta(\alpha) + g'(\alpha) \hat{\delta}(\alpha)$$

Here $\hat{\delta}(\alpha)$ is fully determined by $\delta$ as

$$0 = \hat{\delta}(f(\alpha)) = f^\delta(\alpha) + f'(\alpha) \hat{\delta}(\alpha)$$

so

$$ \hat{\delta}(\alpha) = -f^\delta(\alpha)/f'(\alpha)$$

It is easy to calculate that $\hat{\delta}(h(\alpha)f(\alpha)) = 0$ (one uses here $(g h)^\delta = g^\delta h + g h^\delta$), so $\hat{\delta}$ is well-defined. Also $\hat{\delta}(g(\alpha) h(\alpha)) = g(\alpha) \hat{\delta}(h(\alpha)) + h(\alpha) \hat{\delta}(g(\alpha))$ is just a simple calculation. Finally one has to verify that the map is $K$-linear, that is $\widehat{\gamma \delta} = \gamma \hat{\delta}$ for all $\gamma \in K$.

The inverse map $\delta \in \Der_k(K,K) \mapsto \widetilde{\delta} \in \Der_k(F,K)$ is simply $\delta \mapsto \delta \circ i$, where $i:F \to K$ is the canonical inclusion.